# How to Insert values in database table where ID is max

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I want to insert some values in the database table where the transaction id is maximum.How can I do that ?

```
    INSERT INTO transaction_db (score1,score2) 
    VALUES ('1','1') 
    WHERE transaction_id=(Select MAX(transaction_id) from transaction_db)
```

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'where transaction_id3=(Select MAX(transaction_id3) from
>   transaction3_db)' at line 1

Comment: This looks like an attempt to `UPDATE` using `INSERT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `UPDATE`. You can try.

```
UPDATE transaction_db 
SET score1 = 1, score2 = 1
ORDER BY transaction_id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `UPDATE` command to change the values at a particular row. `INSERT` is used to add a new row. There is no use for `WHERE` in `INSERT`.

```
UPDATE transaction_db set score1 = 1, score2 = 1 where transaction_id=(Select MAX(transaction_id) from transaction_db)
```

Comment: @Sarath Mohan @A J No its not working.the Error says:Table 'transaction_db' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

Comment: @Soumya @ AJ My bad. It wont work. Some kind of db open channel issue? Not yet supported in MySql. The inner query must run first right? Thanks for the update. :)